# Change default SharePoint web page

Tags: sharepoint

I have an app running on top of sharepoint.

Can I change, through configuration, the default web page for a Sharepoint site to a sub-site page? I tried changing it in IIS but it simply doesn't work: The current default page isn't mapped there, anyway.

I would like to change it from "http://server/default.aspx" to, say, "http://server/test/default.aspx".

Edit: I am using SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the web.config file with these lines (under system.web):

```
<urlMappings enabled="true"> 
     <add url="~/" mappedUrl="/test/default.aspx"/> 
</urlMappings>
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A specific sharepoint version would help for more specific commentary, but this would be configured in the SP Siite Admin interface, not directly in IIS.

Comment: Are you able to log into the SP "Central Aministration" interface?  It should be available from the current default page.  From there, to go Application Management, and create a site collection - point that to your custom app's default page.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my clients' Sys Admins won't let me create another site collection. Also, I couldn't edit the default page at "Central Administration" on my test env (couldn't find the option to change the default or to forward / to /test/).

Also tried adding <urlMappings> to my web.config, no succes though. Any other hint?

Comment: Wow, my bad... I got an error on urlMappings. This worked for me as a charm:
<urlMappings enabled="true">
<add url="~/" mappedUrl="/test/default.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>

Comment: Editing the page directly may not work long-term, as I believe SP will re-create some of its code as changes are made to the main interface.  However, I'm glad you found a fix.  ;)